Is there lysozyme in cooked egg whites?
Egg whites are a phenomenal source of the antibacterial enzyme lysozyme.
I was wondering if eggs are cooked, will they retain there lysozyme count?
And will cooked lysozyme retain its antibacterial properties?

Hi and welcome (apologies if this comment seems unwelcoming.) This site strongly recommends evidence of prior research attempting to answer your question (e.g. a quote and a link). Proteins are all still there on cooking, but most proteins are denatured with sufficient heat. Did you google search Is egg lysosome denatured by cooking? (Most - not all - denatured proteins don't function.) If so, what is confusing about what you found? A quote and a link is helpful to getting an accurate answer. Thanks!


amount depends on how you cooked it (i.e., at what heat). hard boiled eggs vs. scrambled @ medium/low heat

i presume a tiny amount of lysozyme would be present (someone probably found a quantitative answer in a research experiment, i don't know) but the egg would predominantly denature the enzyme, causing it to not be active anymore


